MacOS split DNS not working as intended
I have a split DNS configuration setup by a VPN profile
$ scutil --dns

[...removed for conciseness, but basically the standard output of this command...]

resolver #2
  search domain[0] : my-domain.ch
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.11.41
  nameserver[1] : 192.168.11.41
  if_index : 24 (ipsec0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

But when I do lookups for subdomains of my-domain.ch, it does not work
$ nslookup nas.my-domain.ch

Server:     172.20.10.1
Address:    172.20.10.1#53

** server can't find nas.my-domain.ch: NXDOMAIN

It seems to keep using the default resolver address (in this case the mac is connected to an iPhone connection share)
If I query the intended DNS server directly, it works
$ nslookup nas.my-domain.ch 192.168.11.41

Server:     192.168.11.41
Address:    192.168.11.41#53

Name:   nas.my-domain.ch
Address: 192.168.11.43

The same profile does work on iOS. I have macOS Sequoia 15.2 (24C101)
